The union of three points in $\mathbb{P}^2$ not lying on a line is not a complete intersection
Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be the union of three points, say $\,p,q,r\,$, not lying on a line. I want to prove that the homogeneous ideal of $X$ cannot be generated by two polynomials.
Let $[Z_0,Z_1,Z_2]$ coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^2$ then $X=V(p_iZ_j-p_jZ_i) \cup V(q_iZ_j-q_jZ_i)\cup V(r_iZ_j-r_jZ_i)$ for $i,j=0,1,2$ (the $p_i$'s are the coordinates of $p$, idem for $q_i$ and $r_i$). Taking the ideal we get\begin{align}
I(X)= \langle p_iZ_j-p_jZ_i| \,i,j=0,1,2\rangle \cap \langle q_iZ_j-q_jZ_i| \,i,j=0,1,2\rangle\cap \langle r_iZ_j-r_jZ_i| \,i,j=0,1,2\rangle.
\end{align}
But now I don't know how to show that the generators of this ideal cannot be only two.
Any help, thanks.

Do you know Bezout theorem?

Or you could note that the only way to write 3 as a product is 1 x 3.

Following the suggestions in the comments, try using the fact (due to Bézout) that if $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous polynomials then the number of points of intersection of $Z(f) \cap Z(g)$ (counted with multiplicity) is $\deg(f)\cdot \deg(g)$. In particular, here we are asking for $\deg(f)\cdot \deg(g) = 3$.

Right. So one between $f$ and $g$ must have degree 1, say $f$. Then because $f\in I(X)$ it should be a combination of homogeneous polynomials of degree 1 and thus deg$(f)\gneq 1$. Contradiction.

I suppose simply put, the three points must lie on both of $Z(f)$ or $Z(g)$. That would be saying that (say) $f$ is a linear equation which defines a linear subspace of $\Bbb{P}^2$ containing all three points.
